# some two-letter sequence repeated 3 times? "contentment" and "maintaining" are such words

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regular-language

How many words contain some two-letter sequence repeated 3 times? For example, "contentment" and "maintaining" are such words because "contentment" has the sequence "nt" repeated three times and "maintaining" has the sequence "in" repeated three times.

This is my code:

```
 len([f for f in file if re.match(r'(.*?[a-z]{2}.*?){3}',f)])
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: @usr2564301 The current code does not capture the 2 matched `[a-z]{2}` which is needed to verify that it occurs again.

Comment: Regarding *how would I call a "triple" the pattern of one letter, followed by another, followed by the first, like "ama" or "ere". For example, "amalgamate" has "ama" that appears twice, and "dereference" has "ere" that appears twice.* - see  [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60668836/3832970), just replace `\w{2}` with `\w{3}` and remove `{2}` after the grouping, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qmPbat/4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple regex:

```
.*(\w{2}).*\1.*\1
```

It captures two letters in a group with `(\w{2})` and then that same group with the same letters must appear twice more with `\1`.

Here's an example in action:

```
import re

text = """
How many words contain some two-letter sequence repeated 3 times? For example, "contentment" and "maintaining" are such words because "contentment" has the sequence "nt" repeated three times and "maintaining" has the sequence "in" repeated three times.
"""


def check(word):
    return re.match(r".*(\w{2}).*\1.*\1", word)


def main():
    for word in text.split():
        if check(word):
            print(word)


main()
```

Comment: I have a quick question. Thank you so much by the way!! how would I call a "triple" the pattern of one letter, followed by another, followed by the first, like "ama" or "ere". For example, "amalgamate" has "ama" that appears twice, and "dereference" has "ere" that appears twice.

Comment: @DylanYoung same basic principle, you capture the first letter in a group and then reference that group later with \1 or \2

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\b(?=\w*(\w{2})(?:\w*\1){2})\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qmPbat/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?=\w*(\w{2})(?:\w*\1){2})` - that is immediately followed with 0+ word chars, then two word chars are captured into Group 1 and then there must be two repetitions of any 0+ word chars followed with the same value as in Group 1
- `\w+` - consumes one or more word chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kVtBT5):

```
import re

text = "contentment and maintaining are such words"
print ( [x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'\b(?=\w*(\w{2})(?:\w*\1){2})\w+', text)] )
# =>  ['contentment', 'maintaining']
print ( len([x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'\b(?=\w*(\w{2})(?:\w*\1){2})\w+', text)]) )
# => 2
```